# Why wait/notify is not happening here?

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm trying consumer producer problem with int itemHolder with only one entry. I dont know why the consumer thread is not notifying the producer thread when it has put the item, The expected behaviour is that the consumer thread waits till the producer puts the item in itemHolder.
On the other hand when I use locking on an external mutax object it works perfectly.

```
public class ProducerConsumer {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new ProducerConsumer().execute();
    }

    private volatile int itemHolder = -1; // -1 value represent that ItemHolder is empty

    private void execute() {
        final Thread producer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                    synchronized (this){
                        while (itemHolder != -1){ // ItemHolder is full
                            try {
                                this.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        itemHolder = i;
                        notify();
                        System.out.println(String.format("producer: ItemHolder has value, Consumer notified..."));

                    }
                }

            }


        }, "Producer-thread");

        final Thread consumer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true){
                    synchronized (producer){
                        try {
                            while (itemHolder == -1){ // Don't consume if itemHolder don't have a value
                                producer.wait();
                            }
                            System.out.println(String.format("CONSUMER: consuming %s...", itemHolder));
                            itemHolder = -1;    // re-initialize the itemHolder
                            producer.notify();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }, "Consumer-thread");

        consumer.start();
        producer.start();

    }
```

**With locking on external Mutex**
 This works correctly as expected.

```
public class ProducerConsumerWithMutex {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        new ProducerConsumerWithMutex().execute();
    }
    private final String mutex = "";
    private volatile int itemHolder = -1;

    private void execute() {
        final Thread producer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
                    synchronized (mutex){
                        while (itemHolder != -1){ // itemHolder is full
                            try {
                                mutex.wait();
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                        itemHolder = i;
                        System.out.println(String.format("producer: producing %s...", i));
                        mutex.notify();
                        System.out.println(String.format("producer: Consumer notified, itemHolder has item..."));

                    }
                }

            }


        }, "Producer-thread");

        final Thread consumer = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true){
                    synchronized (mutex){
                        try {
                            while (itemHolder == -1){
                                System.out.println("CONSUMER: itemHolder is empty, waiting...");
                                mutex.wait();
                            }
                            System.out.println(String.format("CONSUMER: consuming %s...", itemHolder));
                            itemHolder = -1;
                            mutex.notify();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }, "Consumer-thread");

        consumer.start();
        producer.start();

    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in the first producer, you synchronize on `this`, which is the `Runnable`, not the producer itself.

So you would need to use `synchronized(producer)` instead, except that it won't compile because `producer` is not available yet on that line.

Alternatively you could name your Runnable:

```
Runnable producerRunnable = ...; //synchronized on this
```

and in your consumer:

```
synchronized(producerRunnable) {...}
```

But your second approach with a separate mutex is preferable, except that locking on `""` is an extremely bad idea as this is a global constant (the empty string is in the string pool). You should prefer something like this instead:

```
private final Object mutex = new Object();
```

Comment: Yes, the mutex should be an Object() instead. buy I did not get how would I synchronize the producer thread. How would moving out the producerRunnable cause the sync. on producer thread to happen?

Comment: the `synchronized(this)` in your first producer synchronizes on the Runnable, not on the Thread. And in your consumer, when you call `synchronized(producer)` you synchronize on the Thread not the Runnable. So you are using two different locks. And because the Runnable instance in your producer Thread does not have a name (it is anonymous), there is no way you can use it as a lock, unless you give it a name (my first proposal).

Answer (score 1):

Wait notify works when both the threads are using the same object/ class lock. In your case the locks used for wait/notify are different as mentioned here:

```
synchronized(producer) // lock on producer object

synchronized(this) // Runnable object.
```

Answer (score 0):

After supportig assylias' answer here is another option.

```
private Object lock = new Object();
```

to lock

```
synchronized (lock){
      lock.wait();
}
```

to unlock

```
synchronized (lock){
      lock.notify();
}
```